# Web enabled password manager

Tags: passwords, password-management, password-protection

I am looking for a password manager that suits the needs of a small team. Each team member needs their own vault, and that vault cannot be restricted to a single machine, as members change computers a lot.

So i need a password manager with a central storage, that can be accessed by different users from changing computers, preferably through a client.

To make matters worse, we are in a mixed OS environment so we are running both Debian, Redhat and Windows. AND we can't use an externally hosted service, it has to run inhouse.

Does anyone know of a distributed password vault that suits my needs?

Answer (score 1):

I would contact www.lastpass.com and ask about enterprise vault storage. You may be able to have something designed to suit your mixed environment. If I come across any other solution for something managed in-house, I'll update the answer. As a guess, I would centralize it to a webserver in-house and create something similiar to how www.lastpass.com has done for the public.

Comment: Although I would normally jump at the chance to do custom development I would like something that has already gotten the worst mistakes and errors beaten out of it:) At least for something as critical as this, but yes i realize it may come to it.

Comment: Lastpass has an enterprise solution that is stored locally